# C# MVC delegation failing in Chrome and MobileIron browswer, but not in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kerberos, mobileiron

I have a web app that is attempting to use delegation for retrieving files and making requests to other servers.

I have Kerberos all set up and running fine (I think), but the delegation is only working in IE.

The code

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

// Do some stuff here

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

I then have some logging in the impersonated section that looks like

```
var identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
logger.Debug("ImpersonationLevel: {0}", identity.ImpersonationLevel);
```

When I run the site from IE, the `ImpersonationLevel = Delegation` and the app is able to make the double-hop to the second server.

When I run from Chrome or the MobileIron web@work browser, I get `ImpersonationLevel = Impersonation` and the double-hop fails.

The MobileIron part is especially important, so I'm trying to figure out if it's something on my end, or the client.